# Error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" despite not using atomic vectors or $

Tags: r, operators, atomic-values

**Hello fellow Stackers!** This is my first question so i am curious if you can help me! :)

First: I checked similar questions and unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me. Tried it for nearly 3 days now :/ Since I am working with sensitive data I cannot provide the original table for reprex, unfortunately. However I will create a small substitutional example-table for testing.

### To get to the problem:

I want to predict a norm value using the package "CNorm". It requires raw data, classification data, a model and min/max values and some other things that are less important. The problem is: Whatever I do, whatever Data-type and working directory I use, it gives me the error *"$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"* to change that I transformed the original .sav-file to a Dataframe. Well- nothing happened. I tested the type of the data and it said dataframe, not atomic vector. Also i tried using "[1]" for location or ["Correct"] for names but still the same error showed up. Same for using 2 single Dataframes, using lists. I have tried to use $ to check, if i get a different error but also the same. I even used another workspace to check if the old workspace was bugged.

So maybe I just did really stupid mistakes but I really tried and it did not work out so I am asking you, what the solution might be. **Here is some data to test! :)**

```
install.packages("haven")
library(haven)
install.packages("CNORM")
library(CNORM)

SpecificNormValue <- predictNorm((Data_4[1]),(Data_4[2]),model = T,minNorm = 12, maxNorm = 75, force = FALSE, covariate = NULL)
```

So that is one of the commands I used on the Dataframe "Data_4". I also tried not using brackets or using "xxx" to get the column names but to no avail.

**The following is the example Dataframe.** *To test it more realistic I would recommend an Exel-file with 2 columns and 900 rows(+ Column title) (like the original). The "correct"-values can be random selected by Excel and they differ from 35 to 50, the age differs from 6 to 12.*

| Correct | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | 6 |
| 45 | 7 |
| 50 | 6 |
| 35 | 6 |

I really hope someone of you can figure out the problem and how I get the command properly running. I really have no other idea right now.

**Thanks for checking my question and thanks in advance for your time! I would be glad to hear from you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of that error isn't your data, it's the third argument to predictNorm: `model = T`. According to the predictNorm documentation, this is supposed to be a "regression model or a cnorm object". Instead you are passing in a logical value (`T = TRUE`) which is an atomic vector and causes this error when predictNorm tries to access the components of the model with `$`.

I don't know enough about your problem to say what kind of model you need to use to get the answer you want, but for example passing it an object constructed  by `cnorm()` returns without an error using your data and parameters (there are some warnings because of the small size of your test dataset):

```r
library(haven)
library(cNORM)
#> Good morning star-shine, cNORM says 'Hello!'

Data_4 <- data.frame(correct = c(40, 45, 50, 35),
                     age = c(6,7,6,6))

SpecificNormValue <- predictNorm(Data_4$correct, 
                                 Data_4$age, 
                                 model = cnorm(Data_4$correct, Data_4$age), 
                                 minNorm = 12, 
                                 maxNorm = 75, 
                                 force = FALSE,
                                 covariate = NULL)
#> Warning in rankByGroup(raw = raw, group = group, scale = scale, weights =
#> weights, : The dataset includes cases, whose percentile depends on less than
#> 30 cases (minimum is 1). Please check the distribution of the cases over the
#> grouping variable. The confidence of the norm scores is low in that part of the
#> scale. Consider redividing the cases over the grouping variable. In cases of
#> disorganized percentile curves after modelling, it might help to reduce the 'k'
#> parameter.
#> Multiple R2 between raw score and explanatory variable: R2 = 0.0667
#> Warning in leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax, force.in =
#> force.in, : 21 linear dependencies found
#> Reordering variables and trying again:
#> Warning in log(vr): NaNs produced
#> Warning in log(vr): NaNs produced
#> Specified R2 falls below the value of the most primitive model. Falling back to model 1.
#> R-Square Adj. = 0.993999
#> Final regression model: raw ~ L4A3
#> Regression function: raw ~ 30.89167234 + (6.824413606e-09*L4A3)
#> Raw Score RMSE = 0.35358
#> 
#> Use 'printSubset(model)' to get detailed information on the different solutions, 'plotPercentiles(model) to display percentile plot, plotSubset(model)' to inspect model fit.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note I used `Data_4$age` and `Data_4$correct` for the first two arguments. `Data_4[,1]` and `Data_4[[1]]` also work, but `Data_4[1]` doesn't, because that returns a subset of a data frame not a vector as expected by predictNorm.

Comment: It says "avoid thanks" in comments but: Thank you! For the quick and useful reply! It is really relieving that I just did a stupid mistake and the system works according to plan. I will test it with a new model now and not that atomic vector. The reason I used it in the first place was that the example command for the model did not worked out for me so I thought with T I could get T-Values. Oh boy, was I wrong! :) Somehow I can't upvote your answer because I do not have 15 reputation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah yes! I am new here, thanks for the advice :) Did it. Thanks again!