# Error in ..........: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors JSON-like Format

Tags: json, vector, atomic

The aim is to sum all people with a Western_migration_background or mon_western_migation_background. so I have summed all men and women from all municipalities of The Netherlands which works nicely and as expected however for the migration it does not work  - it either returns a null / NA of the error message regarding atomic vectors.

with the below code I get the number but now trying to get it summed for a single municipal with seven postal codes I am running in circles

######`your text`data[["Aalburg"]][["4261"]][["migration"]][["western_migration_background"]]
[1] 245

#####`your text`$`4261`$migration
western_migration_background non_western_migration_background
245                              160

```
 results_non_western <- get_relative_migration_counts(data, non_western_only = TRUE)
aalburg_data <- data[["Aalburg"]][["4261"]][["migration"]]
non_western_migration_background <- aalburg_data[["non_western_migration_background"]]
total_non_western_count <- sum(non_western_migration_background)

print(total_non_western_count)
```

this one works but trying to make it dynamic fails

Looking for the sum of all non_western_migrants and the relative share of this group but I fail to do so.
it is either zero or atomic vector issue

Comment: What programming (scripting?) language is this?

Comment: Is this R?  Questions like [Error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" despite not using atomic vectors or $](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65196605) have been mis-tagged [atomic] before.  R uses "atomic" in the sense of "primitive" or "most basic building block" I think, as a property of a type rather than an operation (like load, store, or RMW) which the [tag:atomic] tag is about.  Unless operations on such vectors are atomic in R, via software locking?